# PPTP error when connecting from virtual box

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, vpn

I have an application that establishes PPTP VPN connection to the remote server. Also I have virtual box (with windows 7) installed on my machine. The problem is that on my host machine (Win10) the application connects without a problem, while on virtual machine it fails to connect reporting 806 error. I already tried to turn off Firewall on both host and virtual machines and also tried to configure rules (for allowing 1723 port and GRE protocol, both inbound and outbound), but for some reason I still get 806 error, what may be the problem here?

Comment: Most likely you are using a NAT network for virtual box.

Comment: @EugenRieck indeed, that was an issue, thank you, changed to bridge and now everything works.